# HTML/CSS Resize Delema

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am working on a mockup webpage for a black friday project in a community class.

I thought everything was ok, until I realized that the image was to big for really any screen smaller than 1920x1080. Is there a way I can get an image to re size inside my div? I may not be explaining this right so I'll let the screenshot and code speak for itself.

The jfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Eb9mJ/

```
*I need code for jfiddle*
```

And here is my annotated screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2YHu.png

Thanks, and sorry if i am breaking some sort of hidden rule or something with the post, i'm new to the site and have only posted once before.

Comment: Add some real code in your question, and not some pseudo code just to get over the requirement. It's there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first remove the size from the parent container, `#cf` and change the position rule to `static` or `relative`. Then, give the `#cf img` selector a `width:100%` rule.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Eb9mJ/1/

CSS:

```
#cf {
  position: relative; /* CHANGED FROM ABSOLUTE */
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto; 
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%; /*ADD THIS WIDTH SO IT ALWAYS STRETCHES TO THE SIZE OF THE VIEWPORT*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample I made:

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dq7VR/)

It grabs the users screen size on load and on resize, then adjusts the size of the background to fit the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html').css({
        "background-size": $(window).width() + "px" + " " + $(window).height() + "px"
    });
    $('html').show();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('html').css({
        "background-size": $(window).width() + "px" + " " + $(window).height() + "px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

background-size - CSS property

Answer (score -1):

You can target that image in css and set width or height to your needs.
I have altered your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Eb9mJ/

add these css (sizes just for demo purpose)

```
img.top{
    height:100px;
}
img.bottom{
    height:200px;
}
```